# Creating a Xamarin Bindings Library for a Custom iOS Control

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Xcode version - 11.1
visual studio - 8.3.3

when using the below command -

sharpie bind --output=GCCheckbox --namespace=GCCheckbox --sdk=iphoneos13.1 /Checkbox/Checkbox/Checkbox.h
......

Binding...
System.Exception: Unsupported clang availability platform: 'macCatalyst'
  at Sharpie.Bind.Attributes.AvailabilityBaseAttribute+d__7.MoveNext () [0x003aa] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Attributes/AvailabilityBaseAttribute.cs:203 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0006f] in <3fb92ec709f44a579da6a23087df403d>:0 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AvailabilityMassager.Massage (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.EntityDeclaration entity) [0x00092] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/AvailabilityMassager.cs:55 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AvailabilityMassager.VisitMethodDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/AvailabilityMassager.cs:35 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.MethodDeclaration.AcceptVisitor (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.IAstVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitChildren (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode node) [0x00010] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AvailabilityMassager.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/AvailabilityMassager.cs:24 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration.AcceptVisitor (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.IAstVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitChildren (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode node) [0x00010] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitSyntaxTree (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.SyntaxTree syntaxTree) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Sharpie.Bind.DocumentSyntaxTree.AcceptVisitor (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.IAstVisitor visitor) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/DocumentSyntaxTree.cs:37 
  at Sharpie.Bind.BindingMassager.Massage (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode astNode, Sharpie.Bind.BindingTarget bindingTarget) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/BindingMassager.cs:136 
  at Sharpie.Bind.BindingFrontend.Bind (Clang.Ast.Decl decl) [0x0010d] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/BindingFrontend.cs:93 
  at Sharpie.BindTool.HandleTranslationUnit (Clang.Ast.TranslationUnitDecl decl) [0x0018d] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/BindTool.cs:166 
  at Clang.Driver.HandleTranslationUnit (Clang.Ast.TranslationUnitDecl translationUnit) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Clang/Driver.cs:158 
  at Clang.Driver.HandleTranslationUnit (System.IntPtr translationUnit) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Clang/Driver.cs:148 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Clang.Driver:RunInternal (Clang.Driver,string[],string,Clang.Frontend.DiagnosticConsumer)
  at Clang.Driver.Run (System.String[] inputFiles, System.String[] clangArgs, Clang.Frontend.DiagnosticConsumer diagnosticConsumer) [0x00177] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Clang/Driver.cs:139 
  at Sharpie.ParseTool.Run () [0x005c8] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/ParseTool.cs:581 
  at Sharpie.BindTool.CoreRun () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/BindTool.cs:117 
  at Sharpie.BindTool.Run () [0x00026] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/BindTool.cs:95

Done. Exiting with error code 1.

Comment: Why are you not just converting the code instead if it just a control for which you have the code?

Comment: it's an ObjectiveSharpie bug, take a look at this https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3941
also a side note, binding a native iOS library will give a long pain in the neck, probably creating the thing yourself would be easier

Comment: Is there any possibility to run and debug the library project.?
IOS and Android .
I have created multiplatform library project. i can access everything by DLL. but can not run and can not debug it.